# Is it possible to select all of one type of node in the node editor?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, workflow

I have a project where I am pre-rendering frequently via *File Output* nodes, which are numerous and spread throughout the node tree. Is there some way to select all nodes of a certain type with a key command (same as selected)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a handy dandy little script that will select all nodes of the same type as the active selected node

```py
import bpy

#Get composite nodes
nodes = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes
#Get indentifer of the active node
find_type = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.active.bl_rna.identifier
#loop through nodes
for node in nodes:
    #if node has the same idetifier
    if node.bl_rna.identifier == find_type:
        #select it
        node.select = True
```

In action:

[image]

Comment: Cool, if there is no built in functionality I'll save this into my startup file. Will be very useful.