# Geometry node editor: search and select all nodes with a certain name or type

Tags: python, node-editor, geometry-nodes

Is there a way to search and select all nodes with a certain name within the GN node editor? I asked about this in blender chat in the past, but no one came up with an immediate solution.

However, I came across this blender exchange answer today and would like some help to modify it for Geometry Node editor.

[Is it possible to select all of one type of node in the node editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94873/is-it-possible-to-select-all-of-one-type-of-node-in-the-node-editor)

```py
import bpy

#Get composite nodes
nodes = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes
#Get indentifer of the active node
find_type = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.active.bl_rna.identifier
#loop through nodes
for node in nodes:
    #if node has the same idetifier
    if node.bl_rna.identifier == find_type:
        #select it
        node.select = True
```

(If this is already possible via an existing addon, please let me know in reply, thx in advance!)

Comment: on Blender 3.2 at least this gave me this error: `line 6, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bl_rna'`.

Comment: You need to select (click on) a node first

Comment: @Gorgious it did not work with a node selected (my error happens when I have a node selected)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify it this way to get the nodes from a node space. If there are many geometry node spaces, it will use the nodes from the last one.

```
import bpy

for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    for area in window.screen.areas:
        for space in area.spaces:
            if (space.type == 'NODE_EDITOR' and space.tree_type == 'GeometryNodeTree'):
                nodes = space.node_tree.nodes

#Get identifer of the active node
find_type = nodes.active.bl_rna.identifier
#loop through nodes
for node in nodes:
    #if node has the same idetifier
    if node.bl_rna.identifier == find_type:
        #select it
        node.select = True
```

Comment: I have GN editor open and a Group Input node selected by it still gives me this error: `line 7, in <module> AttributeError: 'SpaceImageEditor' object has no attribute 'node_tree'`

Comment: for future readers, the updated answer now works